# RecyclerView doesn't show updated list on Viewpager2 tab change

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, refresh, android-tablayout

In my android app, I am using a TabLayout and ViewPager2 to show different categories of lists using RecyclerView. When I do additions and deletions and then call `notifyDataSetChanged`, the list changes while I am still on the current tab. However, when I select another tab and return, the list shows the original items that were initialised while creating the fragment.

In the `createFragment` function of the `FragmentStateAdapter` adapter class, I initialise a fragment with the starting data item arraylist as follows.

```
public class DataListAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {
    private DataListFragment[] fragments;

    //
    // other code
    //

    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
        ArrayList<DataItem> dataItems;

        //The actual code returns a different data item based on conditions
        dataItems = dbAdapter.getDataItems();

        DataListFragment frag = new DataListFragment(dataItems);

        fragments[position] = frag;

        return frag;
    }
}
```

In the DataListFragment I have...

```
DataListFragment(ArrayList<DataItem> dataItems) {
    this.dataItems.addAll(dataItems);
}
```

In order to ensure I have the latest ArrayList when a tab is selected, I wrote the following code in my activity...

```
dlBinding.tabs.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        dlAdapter.refreshFragmentDataItems(tab.getPosition());
    }
});
```

Relevant code from adapter:

```
public void refreshFragmentDataItems(int position) {
    ArrayList<DataItem> dataItems;

    dataItems = dbAdapter.getRecentDataItems(null);

    fragments[position].setDataItems(dataItems);
}
```

And finally the `setDataItems()` code from the Fragment class:

```
public void setDataItems(ArrayList<DataItem> dataItems) {
    this.dataItems.clear();
    this.dataItems.addAll(dataItems);
    recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

When I debug the code, even without executing the `refreshFragmentDataItems()` function, I noticed that the `fragments[position].dataItems` variable had the most recent list of items after factoring in any additions and removal of items from the ArrayList.

Nevertheless it continues to display the original list. I tried to move the notifyDataSetChanged() call around to no avail. In some cases it was going into a forever loop.

Would appreciate any inputs in figuring out why the list in my recycler views are not updating when I select another tab.

**EDIT:** On further diagnosis, I found the issue is caused due to the search feature.

I have a QueryTextListener, and commenting out the code in OnQueryTextChange fixes the problem.

```
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                InputMethodManager inm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                inm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(searchView.getWindowToken(), 0);
                dlAdapter.getFragment(dlBinding.tabs.getSelectedTabPosition()).filterAdapter(query);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                //comment below line to fix issue
```

dlAdapter.getFragment(dlBinding.tabs.getSelectedTabPosition()).filterAdapter(newText);
return true;
}
});

This is the function that filters the RecyclerView adapter.

```
public void filterAdapter(String query) {
    recyclerAdapter.getFilter().filter(query);
}
```

When I debug all the steps in the above two functions, the item count in the watch pane reflects the actual count, but when the debugging steps are finished, it still shows an earlier deleted item.

Answer (score 0):

For future use, If you are switching between Fragments within the same activity, you can do as follows:

In your `onStop()/onDestroyView()/onPause()` whatever callback is more appropriate, do this:

```java
static Parcelable recyclerViewState;

@Override
public void onPause() // or onStop or onDestroyView
{
    recylerViewState = recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState();
}
```

And In your `onStart()/onCreateView()/onResume()` whatever callback is more appropriate, do this:

```java
@Override
public void onResume() // or onStart or onCreateView
{
    recyclerView.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(recylerViewState);
}
```

This way you can successfully keep your recyclerView's state in a parcelable and restore it whenever you want.

Don't forget to add:

```java
@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    recylerViewState = null;
}
```